# webpack fails to build due to different directory

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass-loader

I am trying out this boilerplate https://github.com/opencredo/opencredo-react-boilerplate and it works fine if a project is located in:

"/Users/[my_home]/oc/adminUI"

But if I move this boilerplate into my other project's subdirectory with path like:

/Users/[my_home]/Projects/src/github.com/[user]/[project_name]/adminUI

then I am getting errors like:

> ERROR in
>   ./~/css-loader?modules&sourceMap&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]-[local]-[hash:base64:5]!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader!./~/style-loader!./~/css-loader?sourceMap!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/app.scss
>   Module build failed:  @import 'base'; ^
>         Invalid CSS after "...load the styles": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "content = requi..."
>         in /Users/[home]/Projects/src/github.com/[user]/[project]/adminUI/src/styles/app.scss
>   (line 1, column 1)  @ ./src/styles/app.scss 4:14-426 13:2-17:4
>   14:20-432

- npm version: 3.6.0
- node version: 5.7.0
- OS: OSX 10.11.2

Thought webpack shouldn't care about the directory in which it's located.

EDIT:

Webpack config:

```
const head = require('lodash/head');
const tail = require('lodash/tail');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const debug = require('debug');
const config = require('./config');

debug.enable('app:*');

const log = debug('app:webpack');

// Environment
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const DEVELOPMENT = NODE_ENV === 'development';
const TESTING = NODE_ENV === 'test';
const PRODUCTION = NODE_ENV === 'production';
const __DEBUG__ = DEVELOPMENT;


// Webpack configuration
log('Creating webpack configuration...');
const webpackconfig = {
  devtool: config.webpack.devtool,
  resolve: {
    root: config.paths.app,
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },

  entry: {
    app: [config.paths.entryFile],
    vendor: config.webpack.vendor,
  },

  output: {
    filename: `[name].[${config.compiler.hash_type}].js`,
    path: config.paths.dist,
    publicPath: config.webpack.output.publicPath,
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({ DEVELOPMENT, PRODUCTION, __DEBUG__ }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(config.paths.app, 'index.html'),
      hash: true,
      favicon: path.resolve(config.paths.static, 'favicon.png'),
      filename: 'index.html',
      inject: 'body',
      minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: true,
      },
    }),
  ],

  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?/,
        loaders: ['babel-loader'],
        include: config.paths.app,
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json',
      },
      // Any .scss file in ./src/... *except* those in ./src/styles/
      // are local css modules. the class names and ids will be changed to:
      // [name]-[local]-[hash:base64:5]
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: /src\/(?!styles).+/,
        loaders: [
          'style',
          'css?modules&sourceMap&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]-[local]-[hash:base64:5]',
          'postcss',
          'sass',
        ],
      },
      // Any .scss files in ./src/styles are treated as normal (not local)
      // sass files, and so class names and ids will remain as specified
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: /src\/styles/,
        loader: 'style!css?sourceMap!postcss!sass',
      },
      // File loaders
      /* eslint-disable */
      { test: /\.woff(\?.*)?$/,  loader: 'url?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
      { test: /\.woff2(\?.*)?$/, loader: 'url?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff2' },
      { test: /\.ttf(\?.*)?$/,   loader: 'url?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream' },
      { test: /\.eot(\?.*)?$/,   loader: 'file?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.svg(\?.*)?$/,   loader: 'url?prefix=fonts/&name=[path][name].[ext]&limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml' },
      { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,    loader: 'url?limit=8192' },
      /* eslint-enable */
    ],
  },

  postcss: [
    cssnano({
      sourcemap: true,
      autoprefixer: {
        add: true,
        remove: true,
        browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
      },
      safe: true,
      discardComments: {
        removeAll: true,
      },
    }),
  ],

  sassLoader: {
    includePaths: config.paths.styles,
  },

  eslint: {
    configFile: path.resolve(config.paths.root, '.eslintrc'),
  },
};

if (!TESTING) {
  webpackconfig.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    names: ['vendor'],
  }));
}

if (DEVELOPMENT) {
  log('Extending webpack configuration with development settings.');

  log('Adding HMR entry points');
  webpackconfig.entry.app.push('webpack-hot-middleware/client');

  log('Enable development plugins (HMR, NoErrors)');
  webpackconfig.plugins.push(
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  );
}


if (PRODUCTION) {
  log('Extending webpack configuration with production settings.');

  log('Add uglify and dedupe plugins');
  webpackconfig.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        unused: true,
        dead_code: true,
      },
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()
  );

  log('Apply ExtractTextPlugin to CSS loaders.');
  webpackconfig.module.loaders.filter(loader =>
    loader.loaders && loader.loaders.find(name => /css/.test(name.split('?')[0]))
  ).forEach(loader => {
    /* eslint-disable */
    const first = head(loader.loaders);
    const rest = tail(loader.loaders);
    loader.loader = ExtractTextPlugin.extract(first, rest.join('!'));
    delete loader.loaders;
    /* eslint-enable */
  });
  webpackconfig.plugins.push(
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[contenthash].css', {
      allChunks: true,
    })
  );
}

module.exports = webpackconfig;
```

Comment: What's in your webpack config?

Comment: did you locally run `npm install` in that directory ? Have you installed webpack globally  with `npm i -g webpack` ?

Comment: @Vikramaditya yes, npm install is local. Webpack is also available globally, maybe I should remove global webpack?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting working directory and file name in react & webpack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38914250/getting-working-directory-and-file-name-in-react-webpack)