# Getting working directory and file name in react & webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, path, webpack

I am working with a react js project. i am using webpack and redux with that. Here is the folder structure of my project.

```
-assets
-src  
 -component   
  -index.jsx  
 -container   
  -index.jsx
```

For now i want to use dynamic className for the index.jsx files according to their working directory name. Example:

for index.jsx in the folder component, the className will be

> src-component

for index.jsx in the folder container, the className will be

> src-component

I have tried to use npm module path for that. But the __dirname gives the output of the url of the browser '/'. How can i get that pwd from the jsx file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, webpack mocks Node's `__dirname` to `"/"`. You can enable the real dirname by adding the following to your webpack configuration:

```js
node: {
    __dirname: true
},
```

After that, `__dirname` will be set, relative to the resolve context in your webpack configuration.

Comment: It is not working on windows. do i need to change something on that node : {
   __dirname: true
}

Comment: You shouldn't have to. I suspect webpack's own implementation of __dirname isn't capable of working with Windows paths. You might want to open up an issue in the webpack Github repository.